# Is gc always invoked, even when heap space is continuously available at run-time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

According to the *Java Platform, Standard Edition HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide* section titled ["Generations"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/generations.html)

> When the young generation fills up, it causes a minor collection in which only the young generation is collected

and:

> Eventually, the tenured generation will fill up and must be collected, resulting in a major collection, in which the entire heap is collected.

So if the application has finished the allocation phase, and
throughout the execution of the application, the young and tenured generations are never filled (at all, at any stage), then gc will not occur even once?

If it will occur, what is the reason? Because such seems contrary to the linked documentation.

Comment: Memory management is entirely up to the JVM, so a JVM *may* choose to preemptively run garbage collection when idle, if it wants to. Don't know if any current JVM implementations do that, but it is allowed. Your quotes are from a specific JVM implementation (Oracle HotSpot), and is not applicable to all JVMs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So if the application finished the allocation phase, and throughout the execution of the application, the young and tenured generations are not filled up (at all, in any stage), the gc will not occur even once ?

Yes. If the young and tenured generations are not filled (at any stage) then the `gc` **may** not occur (even once). It's up to the JVM runtime to manage memory, and that includes deciding when (or if) garbage collection occurs.

Comment: Can you think on one reason why JVM will decide to call gc ? is there a reason to manage the memory in this scenario ?

Comment: One possible reason, **might** be an *explicit* call to [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) (which is an *advisory* operation, so the JVM *might* not perform *gc*)  or if [`Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#runFinalizersOnExit-boolean-) is `true`. Regardless of there being a reason, Java does not give developers a mechanism to perform explicit memory management.

Comment: @user3668129 the concurrent collector attempts to clean up memory concurrently. i.e. before memory is filled and so it can be triggered at any time. If the tenured space fills, this triggers a "concurrent mode failure" and it drops to the SerialGC.